# Obj-C Cocoa Notification NSApplicationDidResignActiveNotification

Tags: cocoa, nsnotification

I've a class called AppController.h/m I want to make something when the NSNotificationDidResignActiveNotification is sent.
So i wrote this code in AppController.m:

```
-(void) initialize(){
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(applicationDidResignActive:)
                                                     name:NSApplicationDidResignActiveNotification
                                                   object:nil ];
}
```

and then

```
-(void) applicationDidResignActive (NSNotification*) note{
    NSBeep();
}
```

The problem is that the method isn't executed and i get this in the Console:

```
+[AppController applicationDidResignActive:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x61c4
```

I can't get where the problem is: could you help me?

Thank you!

Comment: The Amazing Captain Pedanto says "technically, you don't have a class called `AppController.h/m`, you have a class called `AppController` with a header file `AppController.h` and an implementation file `AppController.m`. Hrumph."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`initialize` is a class method, not an instance method. I don't know this for sure, but it seems that when using a selector in a class method, it also assumes that selector will be a class method (for good reason). AppController has an instance method called `applicationDidResignActive`, but not a class method named as such.

Instead of registering for notifications in `+initialize`, override `-init` and register there.

```
- (void)init
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(applicationDidResignActive:)
                                                     name:NSApplicationDidResignActiveNotification
                                                   object:nil ];
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! It worked! So the problem was that the notification was sent to class and to istance, isnt'it?

Comment: Exactly. That plus sign in the error message was the giveaway.